# Custom Django activation_email.txt

Tags: django, registry, registration, django-registration

we use Django-registration. My users have trouble remembering their login info and their family often have to help them.

How can I add their username and password in their activation email, please? (activation_email.txt)

Thanks

Comment: You can write a middleware that injects the username in the context, and then override `activation_email` template

Comment: See this similar question and my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720154/how-to-add-context-to-the-activation-email-txt-in-django - you have to subclass the view.  The default view in the registration plugin doesn't use a RequestContext instance when rendering the email, which means that middleware can't help - it can't directly edit the context. It can set extra variables on the request, but without a RequestContext instance the template can't access those variables.  Once you've overridden the view to change that you might as well just add to your context in the view.

Comment: Thank Peter, I've seen you answer and you sure know a lot of Django, but, could yo be more specific on how you make it possible to add the username in the activation email?